# Decision trees for advertising data

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, cart

Assuming a dataset with the following attributes:
`Date` (truncated), `f1` ... `fn`, `#impressions`, `#goals`.

The problem: I want to grow **$n$ trees** that would find the optimal selection of features and their ranges in each, and that maximize the goal rate (goals / impressions) for future campaigns with **high confidence**. 
What would be the suggested approach? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for [random forests](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=158806)!: they perform automatic variable selection and deliver a confidence for its results.